# C telling me to initialize variable even though it's already initialized

Tags: c, cs50

I am working on CS50 PSET1. I have the following code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void) {

    float change;

    do {
        printf("Change: ");
        change = get_float();
    } while(change < 0);

    int coins;

    for(int q = change; q < 25; q++) {
        q = 25 / q;
        coins += 1;
    }
    printf("%i", coins);

}
```

I am having an issue. When I try to compile my code with the `make` command I get an error saying this

> greedy.c:17:9: error: variable 'coins' is uninitialized when used here [-> Werror,-Wuninitialized]
>          coins += 1;

Comment: `coins` isn't initialized at all. What's the value of `coins` in the first of the `for` loop? Initialize it: `int coins = 0;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is correct. You never assign anything to `coins` in the first place. All you do is increment its (uninitialized) value.

To assign an initial value, write

```
int coins = 0;  /* or whatever the correct initial value is */
```

As an aside, I'm not quite sure what the intent is, but the following is highly unlikely to be what you want:

```
for(int q = change; q < 25; q++) {
    q = 25 / q;
```

Note how the assignment modifies the loop variable. While this is permissible, in this context it looks unlikely to be intentional.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?